# SQLAlchemy Relación 1 a 1 error al relacionarlos

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

La definición de mis tablas seria:

```
class MobileNetModems(db.Model, BaseModelMixin):
__tablename__ = 'mobile_net_modems'
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
mobile_net_modem_type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('mobile_net_modem_type.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable = False)
sim_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sims.id'), nullable= True)
imei = db.Column(db.String(15),nullable = False)
created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = False, server_default=func.current_timestamp()) 
deleted_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = True)
mobile_net_modem_type = relationship("MobileNetModemTypes", back_populates='mobile_net_modem', lazy=True, viewonly=True)

class Sims (db.Model, BaseModelMixin):
__tablename__ = 'sims'
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
purchase_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = True)
activation_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = True)
deactivation_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = True)
sim_type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sim_types.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable = False)
number = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
country_code_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('country_codes.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable = False)
phone = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
first_pin = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
puk = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
pin = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
notes = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = False, server_default=func.current_timestamp())
deleted_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = True)
mobile_net_modem_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('mobile_net_modems.id', ondelete='RESTRICT', onupdate='RESTRICT'), nullable = True)
sim_type = relationship("SimsTypes", back_populates="sim", lazy = False, viewonly = True)
country_code = relationship("CountryCodes", back_populates="sim", lazy=True, viewonly=True)
```

He intentado hacer las relaciones de las tablas pero siempre me aparece algún error. Me gustaría que cuando obtengo el modem me devuelva los datos de esa sim y viceversa.

¿Habría alguna manera? Si no, al menos cuando consulto los datos del modem que me devuelva los de la sim.